# Apache needs to serve file on same port as program

Tags: c#, wcf, apache

I have a dilemma. I'm using a mono Self-Hosted WCF service on a CentOS with Apache.

The WCF program has to listen on a port, which is fine, but Apache also needs to serve a crossdomain.xml file to allow cross domain calls. It calls the file from the same port the program is accessed from.

So...
If I have Apache serve on port 5500, then my WCF program can't bind to that same port.
If WCF binds to port 5500, then Apache can't serve the crossdomain.xml file from that port.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to host my program on a different port, create a Reverse Proxy in Apache to redirect it to that port.

ProxyPass /Service1Console http://{MyDomain}:4510/Service1Console
ProxyPassReverse /Service1Console http://{MyDomain}:4510/Service1Console